# Need a simple maintainable design pattern for a game in Android

Tags: android

I have a simple game

It displays a list of items that the user selects from with game timer.

I am using native Android widgets in an Activity and a Service to control the game.  This has turned out to be cumbersome and my Activity is getting bloated and difficult to maintain.

1. I have a timer (currently I am using a count down timer)
2. I need to keep track of scores and rounds
3. I need to restore the state when the game changes orientation
4. I need to access a database.
5. I need different states in the game (buttons cannot be pressed, and sometimes they can)
6. I need to pull as much out of the Activity as I can

I don't need a canvas, but can someone suggest the best pattern I could use for this?  What are the main classes I would have, do I need a game thread etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should have an activity for each level. All of the basic information should be in this activity as variables, the score, level, time, state, etc. You'll need to find a way to put all of them into a bundle when the application closes, and pull all of them out of the bundle when it re-opens. Should be fairly straight-forward.

As for orientation changes, I would lock it to one orientation for now, and get the game working. If it can resume state, then it should be able to handle an orientation change, but to make life simpler at first, I recommend you lock the orientation.

Hope this helps!